# Baking normals from high poly model to low poly issue

Tags: normals

I'm trying to bake normals from high poly model to low poly and here is the result

[image]

as you can see it bakes only the normals of low poly model

[image]

I selected my high poly first then the low poly and checked selected to active and the low poly model have smooth shading on it.I think there is something wrong but i don't know what is it
Note:when i baked normals the two objects were in the same place.

Comment: Did you try increasing the bias? Don't  use to high a value though since your mode has tiny holes...

Answer (score 2):

The problem could simply be in which order you selected the two meshes for baking. There are 2 levels of selection in blender when you select two or more objects: selected and active. The active shows with an orange outline whereas the other selected but not active object shows as darker orange/red. Make sure you first click on the high poly then on the low one when selecting:

BAD:

[image]

GOOD:

[image]

Note:

The baked normal map looks like it is for the knife on the bottom.  The area around the round holes seem like a smooth gradient whereas it that was the knife on the top poly, that area would show as flat.

You can see the issue in the mesh here:

[image]

Comment: so what should i do the bad normals parts around the round areas appear in the final result of my model

Comment: you have to fix your high poly. How did you create it?

Comment: i modeled it and i used n-gons and sub-d surface modifier there was some issues after the sub-d modifier but i fixed it all

Comment: apparently not!

Comment: this areas you show are in the low poly model.i understand that i should focus in the high poly model and for the low poly i don't give it much interest   for example i don't need to make all of the model quads because its gonna be a low poly model for games and gonna be triangulated and also the issues of shading on the model will disappear because the model is going to use the shading and normals of the high poly.Please tell me if i don't understand this topic well.and thanks for helping BTW

Comment: My mistake, I thought the knife on top was the low poly! I don't know much about knives!! I updated my asnwer with some new option... hope that's it!